# Jira Xray JQL - Show tests from tests executions that changed the execution status from Fail to Fail

Tags: jira, jql, jira-xray

Lets assume, there are two Test Executions (TEx) in a given Test Plan:

1. TEx for app verion 0.1
2. TEx for app verion 0.2
   Each TEx contains some tests to be done on a specific release version. I try to filter out tests that were executed on "TEx for app verion 0.1" with the Fail status get the same result on "TEx for app verion 0.2". In other words, I want to know, which tests generates Fails both on the former and the latter app version.
   I tried to tinker it out with "CHANGED" keyword and JQL's "testExecutionTests" function, but failed to solved it out.

I'm using Jira DataCenter

I expected some sort of X-Ray's JQL like:
testExecutionStatus changed FROM "Fail" TO "Fail" DURING ("TEx for app verion 0.1", "TEx for app verion 0.2")
But there is no testExecutionStatus

Answer (score 0):

Test Plans are flexible but usually you would have a Test Plan assigned to a Jira project version/release. Then, within it, you would have multiple Test Executions, some maybe connected with a certain revision of the code/build, others with a more recent revision/build.
Independently on that, the current reports don't provide exactly that informatio and what you're looking for is also not directly available in current JQL functions.

Eventually what you need can be achieved using a JQL query. You may need to adapt them slightly.

Tests that failed in a given Test Execution and then passed in another one:

```
issue in testExecutionTests("CALC-232","PASS") and issue in testExecutionTests("CALC-230","FAIL")
```

Tests that passed in a given Test Execution and then failed in another one:

```
issue in testExecutionTests("CALC-232","FAIL") and issue in testExecutionTests("CALC-230","PASS")
```

Tests that failed in a given Test Execution and then failed in another one:

```
issue in testExecutionTests("CALC-232","FAIL") and issue in testExecutionTests("CALC-230","FAIL")
```

Where we have the issue keys of the Test Execution, we can use a saved filter instead with the JQL that will provide you the Test Executions that you want (like the ones assigned to a given version).

```
issue in testExecutionTests("filter1","FAIL") and issue in testExecutionTests("filter2","FAIL")
```

Note that we can apply the same logic between Test Plans using the `testPlanTests` JQL function. More info on these functions [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Enhanced+querying+with+JQL).